# Eclipse proxy settings trouble

Tags: eclipse

I'm behind a company http/https proxy that does not require authentication. I can successfully use it for many other application (e.g. spotify, firefox, chrome etc.). However for Eclipse it simply won't work. I've searched and found many similar questions and many answers, but none of them solves my problem.

So I wonder if I'm doing something that is obviously wrong. I am using fresh win32 installation of **Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: Luna (4.4.0)**.

Proxy Settings:

[image]

Here is the Error Log produced when I try to Check for updates. I cannot understand why it complains about authentication?

[image]

I really appreciate any help I can get here!

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse uses the Apache HttpClient for http connections. Unfortunately, this not  works correctly!

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Disabling_Apache_Httpclient

Try to disable the Apache HttpClient in eclipse.ini. Add this line at the end of eclipse.ini:

-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.
httpclient4